# Global variable undefined - scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope

When running the following code, I expected the alert at the end of the function to use the globally defined variable value for "a" (1), but it instead returns undefined. If the code within the if block is never run, why does the the variable "a" return as undefined?

```
var a = 1;
four();

function four() {
  if (false) {
    var a = 4;
  }

  alert(a); //alerts undefined
}
```

Does the javascript parser "see" the variable declaration within the scope of a conditional expression in the same way that it would "see" it outside of that?

Comment: I think what is happening here is that the a in the function definition is being hoisted to the top of the function, so the a you are alerting is an undefined 'a' within the function definition, since that a is not assigned unless the if statement executes.

Comment: @Brodie: This has nothing to do with function hoisting.

Comment: @SLaks what was trying to say was that the since a is assigned as a variable of function `four` it's being set to undefined inside of the scope of the function before being run. -- sorry if my terminology was off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since variable declarations are 'hoisted' to the top of their scope, the second `var a` is being set inside of the function scope. so essentially it's turning into something like:

```
function four() {
  var a;

  if (false) {
    a = 4;
  }

  alert(a); //alerts undefined
}
```

if you were to remove the second assignment within the `four` function you would alert the `window.a` variable rather than the `four.a` one.

ie:

```
var a = 1;

function four() {
  if (false) {
    a = 4;
  }

  alert(a); //alerts 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

All Javascript variable (and function) declarations are "hoisted" to their containing function.

The `a` local variable exists throughout your function (even before the `if`), but will only have a value after it's assigned.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, I think. There's still the question of "why doesn't it print `1` or `4`? Why `undefined`?"

Comment: @Jashaszun: Because the local variable doesn't have a value.